# Echo a div to header.php from functions.php

Tags: functions, headers, wp-head

Within the  section of header.php I have a div structure

```
<div id="header">
<div id="masthead">
<div id="branding">
```

...

I want to add a div within "branding" - I can do this easily be editing header.php directly. I also think that I can use functions.php to:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_div' );
```

...

and then echo in the code. Is there any way at all I can define where the code should be echoed though (i.e. tell the add_div function where it should add the code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`wp_head()`** template tag is intended to fire in the *HTML document head*, rather than the *page header*, and is used to output script and stylesheet links and tags, and other similar things in the HTML document head.

It should appear immediately before the closing HTML `</head>` tag, like so:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

If you want to be able to output something within the HTML markup itself, you have a couple options:

1. Use `get_header( $slug )` to output a custom `header.php` in a given context. For example, if you want your extra div to output on static pages, then in `page.php`, you can call `get_header( 'page' )`, which will then load `header-page.php`.
2. Add in a **custom action hook**, and then write callbacks for that hook:

   ```
   <div id="header">
       <div id="masthead">
           <div id="branding">
               <?php do_action( 'wpse72753_branding_top' ); ?>
   ```

   Then you can define a callback to hook in to that location:

   ```
   function wpse72753_add_branding_div() {
       if ( is_page() ) {
           ?>
           <div><!-- some content --></div>
           <?php
       }
   }
   add_action( 'wpse72753_branding_top', 'wpse72753_add_branding_div' );
   ```

There may be other similar solutions, but the bottom line is: WordPress doesn't take control over the HTML structure of the presentation layer; that HTML structure is entirely *Theme-dependent*. So, whatever solution you implement will have to be *via the Theme*.

#### Edit

Re: this comment:

> Theoretically could you echo JQuery code into the head via functions.php to create the div?

Absolutely! You just need to hook a callback into `wp_head`:

```
function wpse72757_add_head_script() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// script code goes here
</script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse72757_add_head_script' );
```

This callback would go in `functions.php`, or in a site Plugin, etc.

Comment: Thank you Chip. You see a little knowledge is a dangerous thing! I suspect editing the theme header.php directly is most straight forward - I need it for all content and from what you say I can only achieve that by editing theme files. Thanks again - appreciate the guidance..

Comment: Supplementary question just occurred to me. Theoretically could you echo JQuery code into the head via functions.php to create the div? I'm most keen to keep theme file editing to a minmum because of the upgrade issue.

Comment: *"Theoretically could you echo JQuery code into the head via functions.php to create the div?"* - Absolutely! See edited answer.

Comment: Brilliant Chip thank you. Think there'll be a bit of mileage in this one for me.

Comment: Hi Chip I'm just revisiting this - just looking at your code for functions.php to echo the script into header. Why is there a closing and then opening PHP tag? Also no mention of 'Echo' is that not required in the structure you suggest? I was thinking something like...

`add_action('wp_head', 'add_div' );

function add_div() {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(... script here);
});
  </script>';
    }`

Comment: Closing the PHP tag will cause the HTML content to be printed. So, it is equivalent here to using `echo '<script...`. Also, please be aware that WordPress requires `no-conflict` for jQuery, so you'll need to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($))`.

Comment: Hi @Chip Bennett thank you for that - I guess your second point explains why I can't get it working! The Script Echoed into my head section perfectly as far as I could tell but didn't actually trigger any action.

Comment: No worries. :) It's a common issue; and, thankfully, one that *may* go away in future versions of WordPress. There has been discussion about ditching the `no-conflict` jQuery configuration, since it is technically no longer needed in core. (The scripts that caused conflicts are no longer bundled in core.)

Comment: Hmmm - the revised script doesn't trigger any action either and I tried adding to header and footer and replaced the script with a simple onload alert / hello message in case I got my jquery wrong. Wonder whether code is firing before functions.php has written it so it gets missed somehow.